# Отсортировать ассоциативный массив

Tags: php

Есть следующий ассоциативный массив, который содержит список всех координат:

```
 $array =   (Array
    (
        [lat] => -42.158362
        [lng] => 147.2527163
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -33.8692785
        [lng] => 150.9298603
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -42.386829
        [lng] => 145.742374
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -31.048654
        [lng] => 151.546292
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -35.085088
        [lng] => 138.589769
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -37.885309
        [lng] => 145.080471
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -35.09244
        [lng] => 138.694463
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -34.969993
        [lng] => 138.627648
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -33.914798
        [lng] => 151.005811
    )
    Array
    (
        [lat] => -38.086152
        [lng] => 143.190695
    ))
```

Так же есть переменная с нужными мне координатами в виде строки

```
$var = "-37.885309, 145.080471-38.086152, 143.190695"
```

Как я могу преобразовать свой ассоциативный массив, что бы в нём остались только массивы содержащие нужные мне координаты, не меняя структуру ассоциативного массива, а остальные массивы удалить?

Comment: В переменной нет опечатки в строке? $var = "-37.885309, 145.080471-38.086152, 143.190695" не должно ли случайно быть между 145.080471 и -38.086152 запятой?

Comment: Я получаю именно в таком виде. Что бы было понятней lat: -37.885309, lng:145.080471. Так же есть возможность получать по отдельности в таком формате:
$var = "-37.885309, 145.080471"
$var2 = "-38.086152, 143.190695"

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = "-37.885309, 145.080471-38.086152, 143.190695";
$varArr = preg_split( "/(,|-)/", $var);
$ar = [
    ...
    ...
];

array_walk($ar, function ($item1, $key) use ($varArr, &$ar) {
    if (!in_array(abs($item1['lat']), $varArr) || !in_array(abs($item1['lng']), $varArr)) {
        unset($ar[$key]);
    }

});
array_values($ar);
```

[пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e37e94d11374b24ef80be472dd1af7c176c9b26)

Comment: А если в массиве будет такая пара координат Array
    (
        [lat] => -37.885309
        [lng] => -38.086152
    ) или такая ситуация исключена условиями задачи?

Comment: Я получаю правильные данные, но не правильную структуру массива. В print-r примера есть [1] и [6], как их удалить?

Comment: И ситуация с двумя отрицательными координатами так же может быть.

Comment: @Артём Данилов примените array_values($ar), ключи массива сбросятся (дополнил ответ). Не совсем понял о чём вы с двумя отрицательными числами. В любом случае, минусы не учитываются при сопоставлении значений.

Comment: @StuxForce никак не повлияет на результат.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin через array_filter еще вроде можно.

Comment: @Ajantiss люблю array_walk()

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Добавил в ваш пример тестовые значения из моего комментария выше, они были учтены (( http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e4feaaae2208d33d2c18e6adf2a0c03312ac55c

Comment: Ну, тут для вопрошавшего есть над чем подумать

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярного выражения ищем вхождения нужных координат, в итоге получим массив со следующими элементами:

1. `$matches[1][0]` — -37.885309,
2. `$matches[2][0]` — 145.080471,
3. `$matches[1][1]` — -38.086152,
4. `$matches[2][1]` — 143.190695.

После чего в цикле перебора массива сравниваем элементы `lat` и `lng`, и записываем в результирующий массив все совпадения.

```php
$coordinates = "-37.885309, 145.080471-38.086152, 143.190695";
preg_match_all('/(-[\d]+\.[\d]+)\,(\s[\d]+\.[\d]+)/', $coordinates, $matches);

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (($value['lat'] == $matches[1][0] && $value['lng'] == $matches[2][0]) ||
        ($value['lat'] == $matches[1][1] && $value['lng'] == $matches[2][1])
    ) {
        $result[] = [
            'lat' => $value['lat'],
            'lng' => $value['lng'],
        ];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```